# Htaccess Two different redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an existing htaccess that works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /default.php 
DirectoryIndex index.php /default.php
```

I wish to modify this so that all urls that start with /test/ go to /test/default.php, **while keeping all other URLs with the existing /default.php**.

Example: http://www.x.com/hello.php -- > http://www.x.com/default.php Example: http://www.x.com/test/hello.php -- > http://www.x.com/test/default.php

Answer (score 1):

Put the rule for /test/ in before the rule for everything else, but give it an `[L]` flag to stop the rewrite rule processing there if it matches.

Comment: I tried:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^test/.* /test/default.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /default.php

DirectoryIndex index.php /default.php 

this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (/test/)?(.*) $1/default.php 
DirectoryIndex index.php /default.php
```

Comment: neither of these work. http://www.x.com/test/hello.php still redirects to /default,php

Comment: did you make sure to remove your other rule and use this one?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (test/)?(.*) $1default.php [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php /default.php
```

Comment: neither of these work. http://www.x.com/test/hello.php still redirects to /default,php

Comment: I just tested it in my dev environment and it works for me.  My solution shouldn't even redirect to /default.php just default.php, if it redirects to /default.php then it means that it invokes directoryIndex. Disable that rule, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule /test/.* /test/default.php 
RewriteRule .* /default.php 

DirectoryIndex index.php /default.php
```

You also don't need the ()'s because your not setting the value as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your main folder, use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* default.php [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php default.php
```

In your `./test/` folder *(I assume it is a physical folder)*, copy and paste the same `.htaccess` file.

First, you didn't need the `/` at the beginning of default. Apache will always assume it is looking in the same directory as the `.htaccess` file is located.

Second, Apache looks backwards when looking for an `.htaccess` file. So anything in `./test/.htaccess` will overwrite what's written in `./.htaccess`.